# ValidateCredentials LDAP server unavailable

Tags: active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

Currently I am using PrincipalContext class to call the ValidateCredentials method to check for user credentials. It was working fine with our 2 environment until a rather 'strange' error occurred.

```
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("PrincipalContextConfiguration") as PrincipalContextConfigurationSection;
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(configuration.ContextType, configuration.Name, configuration.Container);
principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);

configuration.ContextType = "Domain"
configuration.Name = "example.local"
configuration.Container = "CN=Users,DC=example,DC=local"
```

Above are the sample of our current code, simplified for easier viewing. As above, everytime we need to validate credential, we will create a new PrincipalContext.

The error that we have is this validate credential works fine if we provide a valid username and password. But for a specific machine, that throws this error, whenever invalid username and password is supplied, exception is thrown with a message "LDAP server is unavailable".

Could anyone point me to where I should start to find the root cause of this. It is strange to us that the method is only throwing that exception when username and password is incorrect. we verify this by using PowerShell to call the method.

And I am not that expert in AD. Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing this exact same issue, but only when connecting over port 636. Default port (389) seems fine. I have a workaround (basically put it in a try/catch), but I would like a better solution if there is one.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you got any lead on this behaviour?

Comment: Just started running into this. Has anyone figured out a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if you guys have found any solution for this, but what we did to workaround it is by specifying `ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer` in the options. This eventually eliminate the issue on that environment, but does require us to setup the SSL cert for LDAPs. I didn't deep dive into the internal (require some decompiling of the library), but from observation, the default option of `ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing` is the culprit. Hoping that someone with better understanding could explain this and help people who have the same issue.